# How do I set a default value of % to a parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I just want to have a parameter default value set as % in the report, and hence have the report automatically run and not wait on me to click "Apply". It shows up in the design view of the report but not in the final report. It even can be passed as a value to parameters when I redirect to another report.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check - is the Default Value one of the values in the Available Values list? Also, make sure that the Default Value is equal to the Value property of the Available Values, not the Label property which is displayed.

Changes to the Default Value property aren't automatically propagated to the server when a report is deployed. This is so any changes you have made to the Default Value on the report server for production use isn't overwritten by the test value used when designing the report. Check and update the Default Value for the report on the server (or even simpler, delete the report from the server and redeploy it).

Comment: There are no "available values" because I want the value to be entered in. I don't have server admin access I just write the reports and copy them into the reports folder. I usually don't have a problem with changes to parameters propagating near instantly.

Comment: *edit: I moved it from the reports folder and back in and it worked. Go figure! Thanks very much :)